# Import into SQL Server with format file and bulk insert

Tags: sql-server-2005, import, bulkinsert, file-format, bcp

Hello everyone I have a difficult problem with using `BULK INSERT` command when I try to import data from text file.

I found many articles and examples in Internet about importing with `BULK INSERT` or `BCP` program, but they not help to me.

The problem:
I make export from Oracle into text file with column delimiter `{#}` and row delimiter `<#>` and import it into SQL Server.

The table is (SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE my_DATA
(
ID_PK     NUMERIC(30)  NOT NULL ,
BEGIN_TIME    DATETIME  NULL ,
END_TIME      DATETIME  NULL
);
```

for Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE my_DATA
(
ID_PK     NUMBER(30)  NOT NULL ,
BEGIN_TIME    TIMESTAMP  NULL ,
END_TIME      TIMESTAMP  NULL
);
```

The file with delimiter is:

```
ID_PK{#}BEGIN_TIME{#}END_TIME<#>296167{#}01/01/2012 01:30:00.000{#}01/01/2012 02:00:00.000<#>296178{#}01/01/2012 02:00:00.000{#}01/01/2012 02:30:00.000<#>
```

The format file is:

```
9.0                         
3                           
1   SQLNUMERIC  0   19  {#} 1   ID_PK   ""
2   SQLDATETIME 0   8   {#} 2   BEGIN_TIME  ""
3   SQLDATETIME 0   8   <#> 3   END_TIME    ""
```

So when I used command:

```
BULK INSERT my_DATA 
FROM 'D:\my_DATA.txt' 
WITH 
(CODEPAGE = '1251',
 FIELDTERMINATOR = '{#}', 
 FIRSTROW = 2, 
 ROWTERMINATOR = '<#>' );
```

It works, but when I try to use format file it does not work:

```
BULK INSERT my_DATA 
FROM 'D:\my_DATA.txt' 
WITH (CODEPAGE = '1251',
      FORMATFILE ='D:\format_file.txt');
```

The error is:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 2 (begin_time).

I searched about this problem, try to change datetime to smalldate, try to change length to 23 or 24. It does not work. So I try to import another table without date, I use numeric column and char columns, but I faced with the same problem with numeric column:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (id_pk).

table:

```
CREATE TABLE unit_table
(
id_pk  NUMERIC(30)  NOT NULL ,
name             NVARCHAR(200)  NULL ,
name_full        NVARCHAR(200)  NULL ,
CONSTRAINT  PK_unit_table_2C1 PRIMARY KEY (bule_biz_unit_level_id_pk)
);
```

format file:

```
9.0
3
1       SQLNUMERIC    0       1      "{#}"      1     id_pk                              ""
2       SQLNCHAR      0       11     "{#}"      2     name                                              ""
3       SQLNCHAR      0       11     "{#}"      3     name_full                                         ""
```

The data file contains only 3 rows (the bulk insert command is the same):

```
ID_PK{#}NAME{#}NAME_FULL<#>1{#}factory{#}factory<#>2{#}station{#}station<#>
```

It is interesting if file contains only 2 rows:

```
ID_PK{#}NAME{#}NAME_FULL<#>1{#}factory{#}factory<#>
```

The result of bulk insert is:

> (0 row(s) affected)

I also try to do example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx but face with error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "D:\myTest.txt" could not be read.
>   Operating system error code (null).

And the last, I tried to use this with `bcp` program and face with errors too.

Can anyone help me with my problem or give me at least one working example with bulk insert and format file.

P.S. I use MS SQL Server 2005 updated to last version. OS is Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Are you trying to skip any columns in your source data? Despite being able to name columns in the format file, I don't think it matters (I could be wrong). It relies on the ordinal position of the column. I've had the best luck using XML format files and the `openrowset` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all. But the problem was that MS SQL Server requires SQLCHAR type, when you importing from text file and it does not matter what column type in the database. In my problem the solution is replacing any column types, like SQLNUMERIC, SQLDATETIME to SQLCHAR in format file.

Comment: After reading up a bit on the format file template you used, it looks like the other types, like SQLNUMERIC, are used for data files in SQL Server Native format. Native format = SQL Server internal binary data format. Since your data was not in native format, it failed (more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173851%28v=sql.80%29.aspx ). Anyway, XML based format files, like in my example, give you more flexibility in using data types.

Answer (score 1):

This is not precisely what you asked for, but I've tested it and should get you where you need to go. As far as I know, the following needs to be executed from the server that hosts SQL Server. You can probably set up a scheduled task or something more sophisticated down the road.

First you need to create the format file. I have put different data types in the example to show how they should be used.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="{#}" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="{#}" MAX_LENGTH="35" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="{#}" MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="{#}" MAX_LENGTH="41"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="<#>" MAX_LENGTH="30"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="RpPrdEndDt" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="ContrCustNum" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ClimateZone" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="BCMsrQty" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="16" SCALE="3"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="RMsrPricePerUnit" xsi:type="SQLMONEY"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Second you need to create an SQL `INSERT` statement for your data:

```
INSERT INTO TableName
            (RpPrdEndDt,
             ContrCustNum,
             ClimateZone,
             BCMsrQty,
             RMsrPricePerUnit)
SELECT RpPrdEndDt,
       ContrCustNum,
       ClimateZone,
       BCMsrQty,
       RMsrPricePerUnit
FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\ImportFileName.csv',
                  FORMATFILE='C:\FormatFile.xml' ) AS t1;
```

And third, if you want to run this from the command line, like you would BCP, you can use this:

```
sqlcmd -S ServerName\InstanceName -i C:\SavedSQLFile.sql
```